# convert NSString to Array on javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, nsstring

I have a string like that.

```
NSString *test = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[1,2,3,4,5]" ] retain];
NSString *sendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"inits('%@')",test]  ;
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:sendString];
```

and I call it on function in javascript

```
    function inits(timings) 
{  
    var arr = new Array()
     arr = timings;

        if($.isArray(arr))
        {
            alert(arr);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('0');
        }
    }
```

It show alert "0". How can i convert it to Array on javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Is `arr` an array? Can you confirm that it isn't a string?

Comment: use `console.log(timings)` to examinate the value.. (in the console..)

Comment: Yes, arr is an array before the command arr = timings.

Comment: `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[1,2,3,4,5]"] retain]` - ***Oh why?*** Why two superfluous calls on one line? Why not just `@"[1,2,3,4,5]"`?

Comment: If this works I'll post it as an answer. Try replace `test` in `stringWithFormat:` with `[test UTF8String]` and change the formatter from `%@` accordingly.

Comment: @ EricG: I use the command document.write(timings), it write "[1,2,3,4,5]" to the screen. And when  I call the command alert(typeof(timings)) It alert "string".

Comment: @ Bo A : it get BAD_ACCESS on this command NSString *sendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"inits(%@)",[test UTF8String]] .
@H2CO3: because that is an demo, and I want to send more difference  string to this function :)

Comment: thanks all for helping me. I got the answer :D
if I call "@"inits('%@')",test]" it will send string to function inits and it cant convert to array in javascript.I change it to "@"inits(%@)",test]" It will send object to this function, and I can do. :)

Comment: @CongTran Oh, I see. (I just often see things like this one without the programmer realizing it's unnecessary - glad to perceive you do get the point though.)

Comment: @CongTran, That was my first answer, which I deleted. Perhaps you didnt see it.

Comment: @ ACB: Yes,I intend to accept your answer but this web report your answer was deleted. Answer again please, It will accept it :)

Comment: @CongTran, Refresh the page. You should be able to see it. I have done an undeletion and it should be visible now. I deleted because I couldn't verify it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Javascripts, but try this if it is always coming as string,

```
NSString *test = @"[1,2,3,4,5]";
NSString *sendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"inits(%@)",test];
```

or

```
NSString *sendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"inits([1,2,3,4,5])"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what timings is being sent back as from the application

alert(typeof(timings));

This will tell you what is coming back and then what you will have too do in order to convert to an array since i believe it will be a string that is being passed back and hence you would have to do a split on it to make it an array.

Comment: it alert "string". "timings" is a string.